# Material UI Popover opens out of bounds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm using the following code in my app, trying to open a react-dates picker controller inside a popover element and for most use cases it works great, only when the button is at the bottom of the screen the popover is going out of bounds.

Is there any way to solve this issue? since from the material ui example the popover always moves automatically

edit: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-https-5w8wb?file=/src/App.js

```
import 'react-dates/initialize'

import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

import Popover from '@material-ui/core/Popover'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { DayPickerSingleDateController, isInclusivelyBeforeDay, isSameDay } from 'react-dates'

const defaultAnchor = { vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left' }
const defaultTransform = { vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left' }
const StyledPopover = withStyles(() => ({
  root: { zIndex: '2000 !important' },
  paper: { overflowY: 'auto'}
}))(Popover)

export default function PopoverDatePicker (props) {
  const { date } = props

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false)

  const handleOpen = e => setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget)
  const handleClose = () => setAnchorEl(null)

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl)
  const id = open ? 'simple-popover' : undefined

  const value = date
    ? date.clone().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    : props.placeholder || 'Select date...'

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={e => !props.disabled && handleOpen(e)}>
        {value}
      </div>

      <StyledPopover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={defaultAnchor}
        transformOrigin={defaultTransform}
      >
        <DayPickerSingleDateController
          daySize={28}
          focused={focus}
          date={props.date}
          numberOfMonths={1}
          hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel
          onFocusChange={() => setFocus(true)}
          renderMonthElement={date => <MonthElement date={date} />}
          isOutsideRange={day => props.maxDate && !isInclusivelyBeforeDay(day, props.maxDate)}

          navPrev={<DatePickerArrows left />}
          navNext={<DatePickerArrows right />}

          onDateChange={date => {
            props.onChange(date)
            !props.keepOpenOnDateSelect && handleClose(null)
          }}
        />
      </StyledPopover>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: if you could put your code in a sandbox it would be good

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-https-5w8wb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with MUI/Popover

if you try to comment `//import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";` it works fine!

You have to check the docs of *react-dates* and try to override the styles:

Check the docs here https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#overriding-styles